# How to find the first message between 2 parties in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a messages table that looks something like this:

```
|   id  | sender_id |  recipient_id |
|-------------------|---------------| ...
|   1   |    23     |       20      |  
|   2   |    11     |       5       | ...
|   3   |    20     |       23      |
|   4   |    23     |       20      | ...
|   5   |    7      |       11      |
```

I'm hoping to find the first message between any two user IDs (the IDs in the `sender_id` and `recipient_id` columns). So the result for the above sample would be:

```
|   id  | sender_id |  recipient_id |
|-------------------|---------------| ...
|   1   |    23     |       20      |  
|   2   |    11     |       5       | ...
|   5   |    7      |       11      |
```

At first I thought I could group by a checksum of `sender_id` and `recipient_id`, and then take the min message ID (`id`), but because checksum is different depending upon order of the inputs, that returns both the first message (the intro) and the first reply. Is there an alternative to checksum in which order of inputs is irrelevant?

Or maybe there's a better way to arrive at a solution.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/476525)</kbd>

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY 
                CASE WHEN sender_id < recipient_id THEN sender_id ELSE recipient_id END,
                CASE WHEN sender_id > recipient_id THEN sender_id ELSE recipient_id END
            ORDER BY id
        ) AS rn
    FROM messages
)
SELECT
    id, sender_id, recipient_id
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id
```

You need partition by the smaller id and then the greater one using a `CASE` expression.

Comment: i like your answer. i dont think u need to use CTE tables. Just group by ur partition logic and use min. for ex
   SELECT 
    participant1 = CASE WHEN sender_id < recipient_id THEN sender_id ELSE recipient_id END,
    participant2 = CASE WHEN sender_id > recipient_id THEN sender_id ELSE recipient_id END,
    min(id)
    FROM messages
 group by 
 CASE WHEN sender_id < recipient_id THEN sender_id ELSE recipient_id END,
      CASE WHEN sender_id > recipient_id THEN sender_id ELSE recipient_id END

Comment: @KMC, that's good to. I suggest you post another answer for that.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for this Felix.

Answer (score 1):

```
; WITH CTE(ID,SENDER_ID, RECIEPENT_ID) AS
(
SELECT 1,23,20  UNION
SELECT 2,11,5   UNION
SELECT 3,20,23  UNION
SELECT 4,23,20  UNION
SELECT 5,7 ,11
)
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ABS(SENDER_ID - RECIEPENT_ID) ORDER BY ID) RN  FROM CTE
```

FROM THIS USE WHERE RN = 1

Comment: if abs(sender_id - receipient_id) is your partition then (10-5) would be in the same partition as (5-10) and (15-10), which is wrong.

Comment: Yeah true, but the answer was just for given data sample

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE messages
(
    id int,
    sender_id int,
    recipient_id int
)

INSERT INTO messages
VALUES
    (1,23,20), 
    (2,11,5),
    (3,20,23),
    (4,23,20),
    (5,7,11)


SELECT 
    p.participant_1,
    p.participant_2,
    MIN(p.id)
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        id,
        participant_1 = sender_id,
        participant_2 = recipient_id
    FROM  messages a
    WHERE sender_id <= recipient_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        id,
        participant_1 = recipient_id,
        participant_2 = sender_id
    FROM  messages a
    WHERE sender_id > recipient_id
) p
GROUP BY p.participant_1,
         p.participant_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the sender and recipient are both integer identifiers, how about concatenating them in a specific (e.g. ascending) order? For example:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(CAST(MIN(sender_id, recipient_id) AS CHAR),
         '-',
         CAST(MAX(sender_id, recipient_id) AS CHAR)) AS pair,
  MIN(id) AS id
FROM messages
GROUP BY pair
```

This way we are guaranteed to get the lower number first, and higher number second, regardless of which one is sender/recipient.

Note, if you wanted the output you requested, you would simply need to join the `messages` table with the above on `id` just to get the exact rows.